# Static extention methods in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a simple extension method that translates any number into a new slightly shorter text. It does this by using the 10 numeric values below 10 as well as the alphabet characters.

So the question is if there are calls that access this method at the same time will the code char1 and char2 be overriden from one user's session by another users session

Here is the code of the methods

```
 public static string Translate35(this int value)
    {   //O is just removed to avoid confusion between 0 and O
        string[] Enc = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };

        int char1 = (value % Enc.Length);
        int char2 = (value / Enc.Length) % Enc.Length;
        int char3 = (int)(value / Math.Pow(Enc.Length, 2)) % Enc.Length;
        int char4 = (int)(value / Math.Pow(Enc.Length, 3)) % Enc.Length;
        int char5 = (int)(value / Math.Pow(Enc.Length, 4)) % Enc.Length;
        return Enc[char5] + Enc[char4] + Enc[char3] + Enc[char2] + Enc[char1];
    }

    public static int Translate35(this string value)
    {   //O is just removed to avoid confusion between 0 and O
        string[] Enc = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };

        var indexEnc = Enc.Select((x, i) => new { charx = x, charindex = i }).ToDictionary(x => x.charx[0], x => x.charindex);

        int char0 = (int)(indexEnc[value[0]] * Math.Pow(Enc.Length, 4));
        int char1 = (int)(indexEnc[value[1]] * Math.Pow(Enc.Length, 3));
        int char2 = (int)(indexEnc[value[2]] * Math.Pow(Enc.Length, 2));
        int char3 = (int)(indexEnc[value[3]] * Math.Pow(Enc.Length, 1));
        int char4 = indexEnc[value[4]];
        return char4 + char3 + char2 + char1 + char0;
    }
```

So what I am trying to avoid is one users data is being manipulated by this method and as it gets to

```
int char3 = (int)(value / Math.Pow(Enc.Length, 2)) % Enc.Length;
```

then its char2 is already set.

then another users data starts the same process and gets to char2 and executes

```
int char2 = (value / Enc.Length) % Enc.Length;
```

does it override the first users variable or is it save because the variable char2 is not static as well.

Comment: "Will it have an effect if 20000 users call the method at the same or close to the same time." What kind of effect are you asking about?

Comment: [Base 36 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base36) isn't new. Okay, yes you can remove O if you like but why not I and B also if the font is ambiguous? Don't *guess* at whether something will or will not perform well or exhibit other issues. If you need to know, you need to set *goals*, then *measure it* via performance and stress testing. If your system doesn't meet its goals, *then* you use the testing to *isolate* what isn't performing acceptably.

Comment: Are you asking if the code is thread-safe?

Comment: I don't get what you're asking but this looks pretty simple and no problem would arise from multiple users calling the extension method. Though you can define `string[] Enc` as a static field of the class rather than as a variable inside the method

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I never said its new. and I and B is not an issue in my, the printing only makes the 0 and O look the same.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever secondly im not geussing I am mearly trying to learn if a static extention method will be accessed by another user while it is being executed by another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods have no side effects. They don't do anything but take the input, process it locally and return an output. So there are no problems with lots of parallel calls, because there are no shared resources to take care of.

If you are using code annotations, you could use the `[Pure]` attribute from either `System.Diagnostics.Contracts.PureAttribute` or `JetBrains.Annotations.PureAttribute` if you are using Resharper.

It could probably be optimized a bit by moving static readonly data to it's own members though.

Comment: What do you mean with "The methods have no side effects."

Comment: @PatrickHofman They don't access class members or global variables or environment variables or anything like that. They get input, they return a value. You could call them "Pure".

Comment: @PatrickHofman Good question though, added a little more explanation to the answer to explain what I meant.

Comment: @nvoigt so because my variables created in the method are not static they every user is getting their own instance of the variables and are therefore not effecting eachother?

Comment: @Neil correct. Local variables are never shared between calls of a method.

Comment: @nvoigt ok one last thing. this is not effected if these methods are in my static extensions class right? because I took this class from a forms application now moving it to web based where static needs to be carefully used. so just trying to avoid problems

Comment: Basically there are two applications of the `static` keyword. As a modifier on a variable, you have to be careful, because it means the variable is now shared between instances. On a method on the other hand, `static` means it does not use an instance of the class it is declared in. So it's kind of the opposite, static methods are simpler in terms of parallelism, because they *don't* share the data of the instance.

Comment: @nvoigt fantastic thank you... I will mark your answer as correct.